# How to find Laurent expansion of $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

I want to know the Laurent expansion of $f(z)=\frac{z^2}{1-e^z}$ centered at $z=2k\pi i $ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $k\neq 0$.

I tried using the expansion of $e^z$ or the geometric series but with no sucess.

Comment: Are you looking for a closed-form expression, or just the first few terms?  (Well it won't really be closed-form, but involving the Bernoulli numbers...)

Comment: @RobertIsrael Actually I need to classify those singularities, as i think they are going to be essencial i thought the only way was through the laurent series expansion.

Comment: Oh, that's easier.  You just have to show that the denominator has nonzero derivative at $z=2k\pi i$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael How would that show that is an essencial singularity?

Comment: It wouldn't.  It shows it's a simple pole.

Comment: Yes I guess my gut feeling was wrong thanks!